# Java preprocessing support in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, ide, preprocessor, intellij-idea

Does anyone know about Java preprocessing support in Intellij IDEA? Probably there are some 3rd party plugins?

Just for example: here's a piece of Java code written for Netbeans (which supports preprocessing):

```
//#if JSR82
//# import javax.bluetooth.*;
//#endif
```

Netbeans built-in preprocessor parses those //# keys and comments or uncomments pieces of code depending on defined preprocessor keys.

I'd expect something similar in Intellij IDEA.

Thanx in advance

Comment: what do you mean by preprocessing?

Comment: Like #ifdef blah-blah as in C/C++

Comment: Are you trying to produce two separate versions of the same library? A version that supports/requires JSF82 and one that doesn't.

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov: by "preprocessing" he means something like that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor  This is **very** common in the mobile world which apparently the OP is working on: it is quite usual to generate tens if not hundreds of different builds of a single Java app.  See my answer, Nokia explains how to use a preprocessor for J(2)ME apps.

Comment: @sblundy more or less, approach is simple: 1 code - several jars/libs depending on device/environment whatsoever

Comment: @SpoonBender - exactly, since in mobile world there're hundreds of devices/specs one need to somehow to deal with them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(this is too long for a comment, hence the answer that isn't really an answer but more of a comment).

I've worked extensively with Java pre-processors and IntelliJ IDEA.  I don't know of any plugin/add-on allowing to work with pre-processors (but that would be *great*).

Besides that, invariably when a discussion comes on Java and preprocessors, people will point out that *"such a thing doesn't exist"*.

Yet of course several of these exists.  For example here's a cool Nokia (you may have heard of that company, they produce a few Java cellphones) article called: *"Java ME Porting using preprocessor directives"*.

Truth is: Java *never* delivered its WORA promise, especially not in the J(2)ME world.

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_ME_Porting_using_preprocessor_directives

Another very valid reason to use custom (sadly custom) preprocessors and code-generators can be seen in things like the (excellent) Trove API source code: basically it's your only way to avoid repeating the same code for all the Java primitives, etc.

I've also heard about people wanting to generate different versions of the "same" *.jar*, without putting all the code in the various .jars produced.  Sure, this can be done in a *"Java friendly way"* using amazing workarounds... But some pre-processing saves the day too in such a case.

Point is: there **are** valid case for Java pre-processors.  I tend to like the Nokia one because it's kinda hard to argue versus that ;)

Comment: No Nokia plugins listed for IntelliJ 10.0.1.  If there's a large market, perhaps it's time for someone to write one.  I wonder what's happening to that market now that iPhone, Android, and Windows Mobile appear to be carving it up?  I'll have to check for some data to see.

Comment: @duffymo: no need for Nokia plugins in IntelliJ IDEA. Nokia has them (also called Nokia developer platforms) - one just need to import them as JDK - and go on :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into configuring different [artifacts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/artifacts.html) for the various versions of the lib and then restructuring your code to isolate the version specific code in subclasses/components that are only including in the relevant artifact. This may be impractical, especially in an existing project, but less trouble than writing a plugin. Maven has similar functionality via classifiers.

Comment: yeahh - at least constructive way - not full disagreement as others do. I heard about such approach, but in my opinion it's too academic and far from practical usage. Anyway my "+"

Comment: @barmaley - I tend to agree. They were just added in the last version and are still in need of polish.

Answer (score 0):

Java programmers don't normally use preprocessers the way C/C++ do. Other techniques and systems have been developed like annotations, code generation, etc. Perhaps if you let us know what problem you're trying to solve, someone will know of a java friendly way to help.

Edit: I think the consensus is that you're looking at writing an IntelliJ plugin

Comment: Disagree... Java doesn't support preprocessing, but IDEs do... E.g. Netbeans IDE supports preprocessing

Comment: Check out this doc from Sun for the why: http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Simple.doc2.html

Comment: @barmaley Interesting. However the culture in java is to frown on such Cisms. I shouldn't be surprised such things exist, but in all my years coding in java, this is the first time I've heard of them. Few java developers are using them.

Comment: @sblundy probably few, but I know a lot of implementations of preprocessing approaches in Java and I was actively using it

Comment: So why are you asking this question here?  Maybe you should be asking JetBrains why they don't support it, or writing an IntelliJ plug-in of your own.

Comment: @duffymo: I just posted questions tagged IntelliJ IDEA -what's wrong with that? And finally I know that IntelliJ's guys are checking this tag...

Comment: Nothing - that's what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Eleven years on from this question, there seems to be the Manifold preprocessor which integrates with the Java compiler and with IntelliJ via a plugin.